# Web socket and push notifications android

Tags: android, sockets, service, push-notification

I have a web socket that I need to receive information from in my android app. Would keeping a single web socket open at all times drain the battery on my android device? I expect that this web socket will only send notifications once every 24-hours, which is why I would like to close the connection, and somehow convert the web socket into a push notification. But, then I also need to be able to send from the android app to subscribe to the web socket and receive push notifications. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using push notifications, which consume less battery of your phone and even more if you only send data once every 24 hours.

What technologies you plan to use?

Comment: There is a third party web socket that I need to receive notifications from though. I have no idea how to convert its notifications into a push notification.